# Extended interface is missing properties which were present on the original interface

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typescript-generics

I am trying to type my request object in the express middleware, and for that I have declared a `global.d.ts` and in that i declare a global space which has the new extended interface like so.

In `global.d.ts` at root level

```js
declare global {
  interface TypedRequestBody<ReqBody> extends Express.Request {
    body: ReqBody;
  }
}
```

And then in my middleware definition, I am using this interface to type my request body like so:

```js
export async function requestHandler(
  req: TypedRequestBody<RequestBody>,
  res: TypedResponse<ResponseModel>,
  next: NextFunction,
) {
  const reqParam = req.params.someParam; //accessing req.params throws error
  // handle request logic
}
```

I was expecting that I would have all the properties of the original `Express.Request` interface  available to me in the `TypedRequest<RequestBody>`, but that is not the case and I am not sure why.

I get the following typescript error:

> Property 'params' does not exist on type 'TypedRequestBody'.

How do I properly extend the Request object from Express to type my request body.

For more context, this is the `Request` interface definition from express:

```js
interface Request<
  P = core.ParamsDictionary,
  ResBody = any,
  ReqBody = any,
  ReqQuery = core.Query,
  Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
  > extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals> {}
```

I have been following [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/typed-express-request-and-response-with-typescript-7277aea028c) with some modification.